# Make Code Fast Execute - replace For loops

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

It takes lot of time to execute these loops due to for loop implementation

How can I replace it to be more fast, the under laying table do not have much records too, plus I have made the primary keys too , but still the for loops are slow

```
     public List<BusinessLayer.Transactions.CDANumberTracking> GetPOUnusedCDANumberTrackingItems(string code)
    {
        List<BusinessLayer.Transactions.CDANumberTracking> results = new List<BusinessLayer.Transactions.CDANumberTracking>();
        List<Entity.Transactions.CDANumberTracking> SoUsedBagList = new List<Entity.Transactions.CDANumberTracking>();
        List<Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking> rejects = new List<SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking>();
        List<Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking> returns = new List<SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking>();

        List<Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking> rejectList = new List<SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking>();
        List<Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking> returnRejectList = new List<SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking>();
        List<Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking> SearchList = new List<SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking>();

        try
        {
            if (!InOpenLookup)
                (Connection as SQL).BeginTransaction();

            DataLayer.Tables.PLSPOCDANumberTrackingDNew sampleTable = new SalesOrderModule.DataLayer.Tables.PLSPOCDANumberTrackingDNew(this.Connection);
            sampleTable.SearchCriteria[0].Value = code.Trim();
            sampleTable.SearchCriteria[1].Value = (int)0;
            List<Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking> results1 = sampleTable.Reads(false);

            if (results1.Count > 0)
            {
                rejectList.AddRange(results1);
            }

            DataLayer.Tables.PLSPOCDANumberTrackingReturnD sampleTable2 = new SalesOrderModule.DataLayer.Tables.PLSPOCDANumberTrackingReturnD(this.Connection);
            sampleTable2.SearchCriteria[0].Value = code.Trim();
            List<Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking> results2 = sampleTable2.Reads(false);

            if (results2.Count > 0)
            {
                returnRejectList.AddRange(results2);
            }

            DataLayer.Tables.PLSPOCDANumberTrackingD sampleTable3 = new SalesOrderModule.DataLayer.Tables.PLSPOCDANumberTrackingD(this.Connection);
            sampleTable3.SearchCriteria[0].Value = code.Trim();
            SearchList = sampleTable3.Reads(false);

            DataLayer.Tables.PSOMCDANumberTrackingD sampleTable4 = new SalesOrderModule.DataLayer.Tables.PSOMCDANumberTrackingD(this.Connection, null);
            sampleTable4.SearchCriteria[3].Value = code.Trim();
            sampleTable4.SearchCriteria[6].Value = false;
            SoUsedBagList = sampleTable4.Read(false);

            //process data...

            Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking temp;
            foreach (Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking rejectItem in rejectList)
            {
                for (int i = rejectItem.From; i <= rejectItem.To; i++)
                {
                    temp = new SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking();
                    temp.From = i;
                    temp.To = i;
                    temp.Code = rejectItem.Code.Trim();
                    temp.GrnNo = rejectItem.GrnNo.Trim();
                    temp.WbcNo = rejectItem.WbcNo.Trim();
                    rejects.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            //returns

            foreach (Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking returnItem in returnRejectList)
            {
                for (int i = returnItem.From; i <= returnItem.To; i++)
                {
                    temp = new SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking();
                    temp.From = i;
                    temp.To = i;
                    temp.Code = returnItem.Code.Trim();
                    temp.GrnNo = returnItem.GrnNo.Trim();
                    temp.WbcNo = returnItem.WbcNo.Trim();
                    returns.Add(temp);
                }
            }


            Entity.Transactions.CDANumberTracking temp2;
            Entity.Transactions.CDANumberTracking temp3;
            Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking temp4;
            foreach (Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking searchItem in SearchList)
            {
                for (int i = searchItem.From; i <= searchItem.To; i++)
                {
                    temp = null;
                    temp3 = null;
                    temp4 = null;
                    //check if the bag is on reject list
                    temp = rejects.Find(delegate(Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking tc) { return (tc.From == i && tc.WbcNo.Trim().ToUpper() == searchItem.WbcNo.Trim().ToUpper() && tc.GrnNo.Trim().ToUpper() == searchItem.GrnNo.Trim().ToUpper()); });
                    if (temp != null)
                        continue;

                    //check if the bag is on return list
                    temp4 = returns.Find(delegate(Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking tcc) { return (tcc.From == i && tcc.GrnNo.Trim().ToUpper() == searchItem.GrnNo.Trim().ToUpper()); });
                    if (temp4 != null)
                        continue;

                    //check if the bag is alredy used in So module...
                    temp3 = SoUsedBagList.Find(delegate(Entity.Transactions.CDANumberTracking cda) { return (cda.Code.Trim().ToUpper() == searchItem.Code.Trim().ToUpper() && cda.BagNo == searchItem.From); });
                    if (temp3 != null)
                        continue;


                    temp2 = new SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.CDANumberTracking();
                    temp2.BagNo = i;
                    temp2.Code = searchItem.Code.Trim();
                    temp2.LineNo = 0;
                    temp2.Location = string.Empty;
                    temp2.WbcNo = string.Empty;
                    temp2.ID = null;
                    temp2.IsReturned = false;
                    temp2.IsSelected = false;
                    temp2.ItemNo = string.Empty;
                    temp2.Status = SalesOrderModule.Entity.ModifyStatus.New;

                    results.Add(BusinessLayer.Transactions.CDANumberTracking.GetCDANumberTracking(this, temp2, null));
                }
            }

            if (!InOpenLookup)
                (Connection as SQL).EndTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            if (!InOpenLookup)
                (Connection as SQL).Rollback();
            throw er;
        }
        return results;
    }
```

the for loop under second for each need to placed ... need some help

Comment: Whats "a lot of time"? which line takes the longest? the new POCDANumberTracking?

Comment: @BugFinder the for loop, I will edit the original code

Comment: No its clear you feel the loop takes too long, but what is "too long"? if its the making of the new POCDANumberTracking, then almost whatever you do it will take the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should factor out of the inner loop everything you can. As the code stands right now, you are unecessarily repeating the following operations:

```
returnItem.Code.Trim();
returnItem.GrnNo.Trim();
returnItem.WbcNo.Trim();
```

I have nowhere near enough information to judge if this will have any performance impact.

Other suspects are `new SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking()` and `returns.Add(temp)`. If `returns` is somekind of ordered list, then this could have a considerable performance hit. If its a simple `List` then it shouldn't and there isn't much you could do to improve it anyways. 
Concerning the constructor, only you know how expensive it is but there is not much you can do to avoid it either.

All that said, your code would look something like this:

```
Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking temp;

foreach (Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking returnItem in returnRejectList)
{
    var code = returnItem.Code.Trim();
    var grnNo = returnItem.GrnNo.Trim();
    var wbcNo = returnItem.WbcNo.Trim();

    for (int i = returnItem.From; i <= returnItem.To; i++)
    {
        temp = new SalesOrderModule.Entity.Transactions.POCDANumberTracking();
        temp.From = i;
        temp.To = i;
        temp.Code = code;
        temp.GrnNo = grnNo;
        temp.WbcNo = wbcNo;
        returns.Add(temp);
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Sanjeewa First off, your edited question has very little to do with the original one my answer refers to. Don't do that. Second, I'm not sure what your are referring to with "exclusion". The last loop with the `Find` checks?

Answer (score 0):

I have to limit the entries coming under the foreach loops, that is best way by debugging the code

so the data layer codes referring in the

```
sampleTable.Reads(false);
sampleTable2.Reads(false);
 sampleTable3.Reads(false);
 sampleTable4.Reads(false);
```

need to modified by including the Item for search (I mean the SQL STATEMENTS)

Comment: there are some points that can be get from @InBetween suggestions